# Match regex with template in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I need to match such thing:

```
pid = '0000000001'
redirectUrlMatch = /https:\/\/example.com\/products\/.*?\/pages\/(pid)\/redirect\/(pid)/
assert.equal validator.matches(html, redirectUrlMatch), true
```

But it fails, because how I think `pid` cant be placed to regex
How I can perform this?

Comment: Maybe this: `redirectUrlMatch = RegExp("https://example\\.com/products/.*?/pages/" + pid + "/redirect/" + pid + "/"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you want put pid into the regex   as below

```
/https:\/\/example.com\/products\/.*?\/pages\/(0000000001)\/redirect\/(0000000001)/
```

you can do this way:

```
pid = '0000000001'
var redirectUrlMatch = new RegExp("https:\/\/example.com\/products\/.*?\/pages\/("+pid+")\/redirect\/("+pid+")");
```